# I can't install Tor on Ubuntu server

Tags: 10.04, tor

I have Ubuntu server 10.04 on virtualbox. I want to install Tor daemon and i am following this guide https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en
I added these two lines in the `sources` file:

`deb http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org lucid main
deb-src http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org lucid main`

But after this when i run apt-get install tor i get these error messages:

`W: Failed to fetch http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org/dists/lucid/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 38.229.72.16 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org/dists/lucid/main/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 38.229.72.16 80]`

Why this is happening?

Also how can i install tor daemon from tar.gz package?

Comment: @terdon 10.04 is from 2010, right ?

Comment: @solsTiCe argh, yes, of course it is. Thanks, comment reposted.

Comment: That's because you are using an operating system from 2010, 5 years ago. The desktop version was supported until 9 May 2013 and the server version until 30 April 2015. Neither is supported any more so you can't expect repositories for it to work. You will have to upgrade your system.

Answer (score 3):

There is a problem on the mirror 38.229.72.16. Needed data are not there anymore.

In fact, the *lucid* packages are gone from all the *tor* mirrors.

You could report this as a bug to *torproject*

**But** you should see this as I sign that you are using a **very** old distro now, and it is time to upgrade...

Comment: Is it possible to install Tor manually from .gz package? 
I am using older Ubuntu version because my laptop is old and newest Ubuntu version doesn't run very well on it, i think some of the hardware components doesn't not support the newest features of Ubuntu.

Comment: You could always do it from source, given you have the needed requirement on your distro. Try https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-doc-unix.html.en. IT could be difficult to achieve if you have never done that before. This is if you are interested in the tor server. Otherwise look at torbrowser https://www.torproject.org/dist/torbrowser/4.5.1/tor-browser-linux32-4.5.1_en-US.tar.xz

Comment: I am trying to create ssh connection over Tor so i guess i need to install the repositories.   
I am not very advanced Ubuntu user but i think if i download the torbrowser it will not be much of use because Ubuntu server doesn't have GUI.